# web-app: namespace of a server function

Tags: python, web-applications, flask

I want to compute functions on my server, such as `median()` or `average()`. Currently I'm doing this by mapping these functions to an URL, i.e. `/computeMedian`. I could alternatively put all my functions into a `/computeFunction` URL and then post the function name with the data. Is there something wrong with this approach or a better way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you think its wrong do it with `/computeFunction`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the approach with Flask.

```
@app.route('/compute/<function>', methods=['GET']) 
def compute(function): 
   if function == 'average':
      return ComputeAverage(request.args.get('list_of_averages'))
```